# Android set visibility of elements asynctask

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, visibility

I am trying to set the visibility of two linear layouts when running an asynctask. Here is my code:

```
private LinearLayout mProgress;
private LinearLayout mList;
mProgress.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                mList.setVisibility((mProgress.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE));               
            }
        });


//When I run asynctask
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute() {                
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

By rights this should set mProgress to visible all the way until onPostExecute. From there, I set the visibility to GONE, which should make my other Linear Layout visible correct? However, when I run this, mProgress is never set to VISIBLE from onPreExecute, and when the Visibility is changed, mList is never set to VISIBLE. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: No interacting with the ui from an outside thread without a handler (which async tasks don't directly implement)

Comment: What do you want to achieve by doing this? Keep your code simple & for your question there are other ways to handle the same things in better way

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things.  Set the visibility of the list directly in onPostExecute and onPreExecute-  its easier to understand and more visible to maintainers.

But your problem with the code as written is onSystemUiVisibilityChange is called before the new visibility is set, not after.  So you shouldn't use mProgress.getVisibility, your should use the visibility variable passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the wrong Listener, the document said that the onSystemUiVisibilityChange() will be called when the status bar changes visibility because of a call to setSystemUiVisibility(int). See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html

You'd better make sure you are using the correct Listener first, and then make sure the onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() method are executed before the callback to the Listener.